# Sum quantities from a second table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table `Owners`:

```
Owner   product
-----------------
Jhon    product1
Jhon    product2
Jhon    product3
Chris   product4
```

Another table `Products`:

```
Product   QuantitySold
-----------------------
Product1      3
Product2      5
Product3      2
Product4      7
```

How do I write a SQL query to come up with the total number of unit sold per owner?

For example for Jhon I should get 10 (3+5+2)

I tried:

```
Select 
    Owners.owner, 
    sum(Products.quantitySold) 
from 
    Products, Owners
Group by 
    owners.owner
```

But that returns the total of `quantitySold` for any owner (17 = 3+5+2+7)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `JOIN` condition. Basically, you're doing a `CROSS JOIN` instead of an `INNER/OUTER JOIN`. My suggestion is not to use the old-style `JOIN` syntax and use explicit `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    o.Owner,
    SUM(p.QuantitySold)
FROM Owners o
INNER JOIN Products p
    ON p.Product = o.Product
GROUP BY o.Owner
```

Reference:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) by Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.Owner), SUM(B.QuantitySold) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Owner ORDER BY A.Owner)
FROM OWNERS A
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS B ON A.product = B.product
```